# How to resize a sprite after changing it's texture

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Say I have a size 25x25 `SKSpriteNode` and I change the node's `.texture` property to a texture that is size 50x50. It seems like it is trying to shrink the new texture to fit size 25x25, the original size of the node. But how can I change the node's size to adapt to the new size of the texture, in this example 50x50.

In short, I want my sprite to resize to fit the dimensions of the new texture.

```
override func applyEffect() {
    switch(tier) {
    case 2:
        sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "clock2")
    case 3:
        sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "clock3")
    case 4:
        sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "clock4")
    default:
        print("")
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I need more info,  what is this texture, is it 1x, 2x, or a 3x image?

Comment: I believe it's a 1x image. It's a .png saved in my Assets.xcassets

Comment: go into your xcassets and click on the image, it will tell you

Comment: Yes it's a 1x image

Comment: show the code on how you are doing this

Comment: I edited some code in, sprite is of course the SKSpriteNode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151567/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-brejuro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the texture bug is back, but only sometimes depending on how you do your assets folder.  I was playing around with this in Xcode 8.3.3 and was able to get it both working and not working depending on how it got configured.  Looks like it is broken in Xcode 9 as well.  As a work around, do  `node.size = node.texture!.size()` after you assign your node a new texture.  Note: `node` is the name of the sprite you want to change in size.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the node to resize when you add a new texture, by setting the resize parameter to true

```
 let newTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "someNewTexture")
 someNode.run(SKAction.setTexture(newTexture, resize: true))
```